# Restrictions imposed on my project when using a library under the GNU Lesser General Public License

Tags: java, licensing, lgpl

I am using an open source library that is licensed under the `GNU Lesser General Public License`.  ([Hosted on sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/javacsv/)).

The library is very simple and just reads and writes to a csv file.  My JSP is using it for input/output.

The download contains these files:

- src

  - AllTests.java
  - com
  - csvreader
  - CsvReader.java
  - CsvWriter.java
- build.bat
- build.xml
- javacsv.jar
- javadoc.bat
- javadoc.xml

Am I restricted to only use the jar file or am I allowed to embed the source into my project?

Does using this library put restrictions on my project?  What do I need to do to abide by the terms of the license?

Would the restrictions be different if the JSP was intended only for internal use?

Would the restrictions be different if this was a desktop application?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing/274964#274964) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139804/can-licensing-questions-ever-be-on-topic) for details, and the [help] for more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not restricted to only using the `.jar`, so you can put the `.java` files into your own project, however, any modifications you make to those `.java` files must be distributed in source form at the request of any user.

You must also provide the minimum requirements to allow a user to replace these files in the combined application. This means, you can distribute your code which uses the LGPL work as compiled `.class` files, such that the user can use your code against his own version of the LGPL work. This forbids you from "protecting" the resulting program to try and prevent such modifications.

These licensing terms only apply for applications you distribute to another person, so if you are using the app purely for internal use, you can do what you want. Any distribution requires you to abide by the conditions of the LGPL.

Comment: Do I need to specify somewhere that I am using some libraries under LGPL?

Comment: Yes. As per section 3 of the LGPL. `a) Give prominent notice with each copy of the object code that the Library is used in it and that the Library and its use are covered by this License.
b) Accompany the object code with a copy of the GNU GPL and this license document.`

Comment: So just to summarize.  I am free to use the library but I must: a) give the source code (for the library) to anyone I give the project to  (at their request) *AND* b) provide documentation with the project specifying that I am using a library under LGPL.  **Are there any other requirements?**